# Should I replace My internal hardisk to a new external one?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

My old internal 1TB HDD becomes so slow suddenly, and I'm afraid that it's about to die, so I will try to copy my data to external HDD.

---

I have two Questions:

1. What's the best tool to copy all the HDD data to my external HDD?
2. I have two options to replace my internal HDD:

   1-Buy another internal HDD.

   2-Buy external HDD instead But in this case I will use it as internal and I will never unplug it from the usb?(Is this wrong for the external HDD?)

Comment: If the 1 TB drive is a mechanical hard disk, then, if the cost is acceptable, I suggest replacing it with an SSD. Of course, backing up your data is the first priority.

Comment: Unfortunately software recommendations are off-topic here.  Its worth commenting that most  external HDD's are lower performance, lower power internal hard drives in an enclosure (eg WD green drives).   Whether you use an internal or external drive depends on your reasons for preferring an external drive and cost.   Arguably internal drives are better from a technical POV as the OS has more direct access to the drive, and the drives can perform faster - and there is 1 less thing to go wrong - ie no USB->SATA step.

Comment: If you remove the first question ("best tool"), IMHO, this would be on-topic.  Although several folks have voted to close this based on it being for "hardware recommendation", I don't feel that's the case.  You aren't asking for a product recommendation, just the right solution (internal or external) to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can copy all your data with the Windows 10 builtin command-line utility `robocopy`, documentation is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).
2. Do not use an external drive as your main filesystem. These drives are connected to your computer via USB which is slower and less robust than SATA or M.2 used for internal drives.